# Count divs and add jquery to expand and collapse Text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hope someone can help.  There are 3 divs with employee-block class in the html code included.  I would like to add javascript/jquery code to expand/collapse anything after the 2nd div (or employee-block div).  This is my html:

```
<div class="employee-block">
    <img alt="test" title="test" src="/images/42.png" /><div class="employee-details"><span class="red strong">TEST</span><br /><p>test description</p></div>                    
</div>               
<div class="bottom"></div>            
<div class="employee-block">
    <div class="employee-details"><span class="red strong">support@.net</span><br /><p>testing description</p></div>                    
</div>               
<div class="bottom"></div>            
<div class="employee-block">
    <img alt="test" title="test" src="/images/42.png" /><div class="employee-details"><span class="red strong">TEST</span><br /><p>test description</p></div>
</div>               
<div class="bottom"></div>
```

I have this jquery code, but not sure how to plug it in. In my example html code I only want to hide/show the 3rd employee-block div, so really anything more than 2 because there could be more than 2:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {        
    $('div.view').hide();         
    $('div.slide').click(function () {            
        $('div.view').slideToggle(400);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I have this jquery code, but not sure how to plug it in.  In my example html code I only want to hide/show the 3rd employee-block div, so really anything more than 2 because there could be more than 2:  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {        
        $('div.view').hide();         
        $('div.slide').click(function () {            
            $('div.view').slideToggle(400);
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

Comment: @obautista - edit your question and add the code; don't post it as a comment.

Comment: @obautista Where are **.view** and **.slide** divs? It seems that you copy paste that code. Try to do by yourself before asking for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear for me, but look at this code:

```
$('a.createSomeButton').click( function() {
  if ( ! $('#IwillCollapse').length ) {
    $('.employee-block:gt(1)').wrap('<div id="IwillCollapse" />');
  }
  $('#IwillCollapse').slideToggle();
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you get on your way. There's many different ways to achieve what you want but this might be the easiest to grasp. http://jsfiddle.net/jSZxp/1/

```
var employeeBlocks = $('.employee-block').slice(2); //returns all after the first 2

employeeBlocks.addClass('hidden'); //attach the hidden class

$('button').on('click', function(){
    employeeBlocks.toggle('hidden'); //toggles the hidden class
});
```